# "Project Target Framework Not installed" error comes when building the VSTO project for Office 2010 in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have developed a VSTO project in Visual Studio 2012 and it was working fine.

I have close the Visual Studio and tried to open the same solution again and i got the following error.

Project Target Framework Not installed

The C#project is targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0", which is not installed on this machine.  to proceed, you must select an option below.

1.Change the target to .NET Framework 4.5.....

2.Download the targeting pack for ".NET Framework, Version = v4.0"...

3.Do not load the project

None of the above steps worked.This is happening when closing the application after first time i created the VSTO excel addin for office 2010.
Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637

Answer (score 0):

VSTO-Projects in Visual Studio prior to VS 2013, Update 3 were hardlinked to a maximum of .NET 4.0. This will most likely also include VS 2012.

Since Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2014/08/04/visual-studio-2013-update-3-released/) you can choose .NET 4.5 (and later) for VSTO-projects. So this is probably a quirky behaviour of Visual Studio trying to upgrade a project to .NET 4.5 because of a missing .NET-installation (4.0) while the resulting upgraded project is not supported itself.